# Changing Bootstrap elements' width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, here's my situation :

- I've built a website using Twitter Bootstrap.
- The main design - among others - consists of a left sidebar (`span3`) and the main content (`span9`).

Now, I'm trying to fit a 728 x 90 AdSense Leaderboard ad in the `span9` block and  - guess what - I noticed it's *slightly* bigger than the available block.

So, I'm thinking about re-sizing the whole griding system (= increasing the grid column width by some pixels).

How should I go about it? What if I go and [**Customize**](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html)? Which variable should I edit, so that the alternative CSS remains a drag'n'drop replacement for the existing `bootstrap.css`?

And, last but not least : will it work without having to tweak 1001 different CSS options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three variables below control the gutter (spacing between columns) in the Bootstrap grid. The defaults are shown below (taken out of `variables.less`. Make these values smaller to make the columns (`span*`) themselves wider.

```
@gridGutterWidth:          20px;
@gridGutterWidth1200:      30px;
@gridGutterWidth768:       20px;
```

The fluid grid calculates it's values from the above variables too:

```
@fluidGridGutterWidth:     percentage(@gridGutterWidth/@gridRowWidth);
@fluidGridGutterWidth1200: percentage(@gridGutterWidth1200/@gridRowWidth1200);
@fluidGridGutterWidth768:  percentage(@gridGutterWidth768/@gridRowWidth768);
```